# Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: property mapping has wrong number of columns: com.sakila.entity.Film.specialFeatures type: object

Tags: mysql, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm working on `Spring + Spring Data JPA` example. In this example I was running my test case to get the `Actor by FirstName and LastName`, but when I run the Test case, I see the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [spring/database-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: jpa-mysql-db] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1582)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1054)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:829)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:128)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: jpa-mysql-db] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:951)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:881)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:340)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:319)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1641)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: property mapping has wrong number of columns: com.sakila.entity.Film.specialFeatures type: object
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:600)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:265)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.validate(MetadataImpl.java:329)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:489)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:878)
    ... 45 more
```

I am using the sakila database from the link: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/index-other.html

```
mysql> desc film;
+----------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field                | Type                                                                | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+----------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| film_id              | smallint(5) unsigned                                                | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |
| title                | varchar(255)                                                        | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                             |
| description          | text                                                                | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| release_year         | year(4)                                                             | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| language_id          | tinyint(3) unsigned                                                 | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                             |
| original_language_id | tinyint(3) unsigned                                                 | YES  | MUL | NULL              |                             |
| rental_duration      | tinyint(3) unsigned                                                 | NO   |     | 3                 |                             |
| rental_rate          | decimal(4,2)                                                        | NO   |     | 4.99              |                             |
| length               | smallint(5) unsigned                                                | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| replacement_cost     | decimal(5,2)                                                        | NO   |     | 19.99             |                             |
| rating               | enum('G','PG','PG-13','R','NC-17')                                  | YES  |     | G                 |                             |
| special_features     | set('Trailers','Commentaries','Deleted Scenes','Behind the Scenes') | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| last_update          | timestamp                                                           | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
+----------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
13 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Film.java**

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="Film.findAll", query="SELECT f FROM Film f")
public class Film implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="film_id")
    private int filmId;

    @Lob
    private String description;

    @Column(name="last_update")
    private Timestamp lastUpdate;

    private int length;

    private String rating;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name="release_year")
    private Date releaseYear;

    @Column(name="rental_duration")
    private byte rentalDuration;

    @Column(name="rental_rate")
    private BigDecimal rentalRate;

    @Column(name="replacement_cost")
    private BigDecimal replacementCost;

    @Column(name="special_features")
    private Object specialFeatures;

    private String title;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Language
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="language_id")
    private Language language1;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Language
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="original_language_id")
    private Language language2;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to FilmActor
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="film")
    private List<FilmActor> filmActors;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to FilmCategory
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="film")
    private List<FilmCategory> filmCategories;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Inventory
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="film")
    private List<Inventory> inventories;

    // Assume respective setters and getters are present
}
```

Please let me know if need any other info.

Answer (score 0):

- If you use maven, put the xml file on resource folder.
- Else, add the folder which contain the xml file to source folder.

Good luck

Comment: I'm using maven and XML file already resent in src/main/resources, still issues

Answer (score 0):

please remove The Object

and try that, it will work

```
@Column(name = "special_features", columnDefinition = "set('Trailers','Commentaries','Deleted Scenes','Behind the Scenes')")
private String specialFeatures;
```